# Firebug and FirePHP only for selected domains?

Tags: debugging, firebug, error-logging, firephp

How can I automatically enable Firebug and FirePHP only for pages in selected TLD eg. `*.dev`?
I don't see any option for this. Maybe some userscript?

Also, is there any way to always start Firebug in minimized to status bar mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is as follows (not tested):

```
$firephp = FirePHP::getInstance(true);
// always disable first
$firephp->setEnabled(false);
if(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], -4, 4)==".dev") {
    // only enable when criteria matches
    $firephp->setEnabled(true);
}
```

This assumes FirePHP < 1.0. If using FirePHP 1.0 it is even easier. You can [install FirePHP](http://reference.developercompanion.com/#/Tools/FirePHPCompanion/Install/) into the site and it will only be enabled if the *INSIGHT_CONFIG_PATH* is set and an authorized client is detected.

I am not 100% sure what you mean about starting Firebug in minimized mode. It keeps the setting from when you last used it. If you want to explore some options we could implement to control Firebug, please [get in touch](http://groups.google.com/group/firephp-dev).

Comment: Thanks, but this just disables the logging, not the Firebug extension itself. And just PHP, Firebug console still is on/off.